# Javascript: Escape key = browser back button

Tags: javascript, browser, keyboard, back

In a browser how can I make the keyboard's escape key go back in Javascript.

For example: if you visit [this page](http://bit.ly/lgmRbW) and click the "Fullscreen" link I'd like to press the escape key and go back to the previous page.

What's the Javascript to make this magic happen?

Comment: `k.keymap=e.extend({},a._keyboard.map);a.attachKeyboard({escape:a.exitFullscreen,right:a.next,left:a.prev});` is the "magic"/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a Key-Listener:

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){ if(e.keyCode == 27) history.back(); }, false);
```

This will call `history.back()` if the Escape key (keycode 27) is pressed.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).bind("keyup", null, function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 27) {  //handle escape key
            //method to go back            }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can bind an `onkeyup` event handler to `window` and check if the keycode is `27` (keycode for Escape), then use the `window.history.back()` function.

```
window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) window.history.back();
}
```

MDC docs on `window.history`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.history

Answer (score 3):

Just listen for key code 27 and call `history.go(-1);`

Answer (score 3):

You need to listen for the 'ESC' keypress, and fire off the back action when it is pressed, like so:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){ 
   if (window.event.keyCode == 27) {
      history.go(-1);
   }
};
```